# I get expected output in android studio but not in vs code with same code

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I am new to flutter. As I have a low end device, android studio don't perform well in my device so, I decide to code in vs code. Problem is when I write any code and run it from vs code, flutter demo home page is shown as output. But when I run same code from android studio I get the desired output.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Myapp(),
 ));
}

class Myapp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Myapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyappState createState() => _MyappState();
}

class _MyappState extends State<Myapp> {
  bool _st = true;
  void _handleTap()
  {
    if (_st){
      setState(() {
        _st = false;
      });
   }
    else
      {
        setState(() {
          _st = true;
        });
      }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: _handleTap,
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: Text(
            _st?'Active':'Inactive',
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: _st?Colors.green:Colors.grey
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}
```

When I run this code from vs code, following output appears.
[image: first]

But when I run same code from android studio,following output shows up
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your project terminal run: `flutter clean`. it will clear your build caches,

run `flutter pub get` and re-run your project. hope it will work.